# Angularjs; Dynamically adding custom attribute directive

Tags: angularjs, svg, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to dynamically add a custom attribute-directive to a svg g element.

Initially I was trying to add it as an element-directive containing a g element template but, I realised that the svg element can't recognise the foreign element-directive unless, I perhaps wrapped it in a foreignObject-tag; which I thought looked sloppy.

I have a function in a service that creates a svg element and returns a jquery object, which takes the tag name and attrs as arguments.

I know how to create element-directives dynamically but, how would I attach this attribute-directive to a g element?

---

**Update:**

The directive in question only appends svg elements to a pre-existing svg canvas, for the moment.
It has functions to manipulate the data within the elements as well but, I can't use any of that until the svg can draw it.

```
// customeDirect.js

(function() {
    angular.module('app')
        .directive('customDirect', function() {
            var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
            };

            var controller = function($scope, $element) {
                $scope.visible = true;
            };

            return {
                link: linker,
                controller: controller,
                template: '<g class="group" ng-show="visible">'       +
                              '<ellipse class="body" rx="50" ry="33"' +
                                   'cx="100" cy="83">'                +
                              '</ellipse>'                            +
                              '<g class="content"></g>'               +
                          '</g>',
                restrict: 'AE'
            }
        })
    ;
})();
```

How can I attach this to pre existing svg element or g tag?

Comment: What is g-tag ? is that an angular directive ? Or something that come from another library ? If it's a directive you'll need to use $decorator and change what you need (like the link function). If it's not a andgular directive you'll need to create the said directive.

Comment: It's part of svg, it's a tag that defines a group of svg elements. You can use it encapsulate styles to apply to all svg objects inside (for example: circle rectangle line). I just use them as a container for a group of svg elements.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g

Comment: Apologies if it was confusing with using snake case. The stack overflow text editor was having a fit because I was using angle brackets with the g tag.

Comment: Well since it's from svg, you'll probably need to wrap the g-tag in a directive in order to handle custom data. However i don't know anything from svg. I think you need to detail what exactly that custom attribute is suppose to do and to set a plnkr. Otherwise people will have an hard time answering you.

Comment: I already tried wrapping the g tag in a element directive. Unfortunately svg doesn't draw it because the directive is not an svg element, even though it contains svg elements. That's why I was trying to add the directive as a attribute to the g tag. But I don't know how to do that. I'll update the question.

Comment: I read something about svg elements not rendering properly unless defined as "SVG subdocuments", whatever that means. 
I'll have to study this a bit more.
Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject